# Is decent amount a correct collocation?

Tags: collocations, comparative-constructions

In the following sentence, is "decent amount of money" a sensible and correct collocation?

> I have always dreamed of earning a **decent amount of money** to live my livelihood.

Is it wordy to say "decent amount of money"? I mean, Is it better to just say "decent money" instead of "decent amount of money"?

> - decent amount of money
> - decent money

Could you please give me an alternative if none of these phrases are good?

Comment: Both phrases are commonly used to express a satisfactory, although undefined, amount of money.

Comment: Yes. In British English we might even just say that a job pays "decent money".

Comment: Using 'decent' to describe a sum of money, salary, price, etc, is understandable in UK English, but is informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Earning a decent amount of money” could be said to focus on the point after the money has been earned, or at least the amount of money being viewed as one single amount or sum of money, whereas “earning decent money” refers more to the person’s salary, and the idea that the money will be coming to the person consistently over time.

“Earning a decent amount of money” could also be used to mean the latter, but it wouldn’t work the other way round.

So there are differences in when the two different expressions would be used.